# Each prior adverb in J

Tags: j

In Q/kdb you can modify a verb easily with `':` which represents each-prior. It will apply the verb to an element and it's previous neighbor. For example

`=':` checks if pairs of values are equal. In J, you can easily fold `/\` but it is cumulative, is there a pairwise version of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` has a [dyadic valence](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/bslash#dyadic) to select lists of a particular length, with different behavior depending on positive and negative lengths:

```
   2]\i.4
0 1
1 2
2 3
   3]\i.4
0 1 2
1 2 3
   _2]\i.4
0 1
2 3
   _3]\i.4
0 1 2
3 0 0
```

So for comparing pairs:

```
   n=:1 2 2 2 3 3 1
   2]\n
1 2
2 2
2 2
2 3
3 3
3 1
   =/"(1) 2]\n
0 1 1 0 1 0
   _2]\n
1 2
2 2
3 3
1 0
   =/"(1) _2]\n
0 1 1 0
```

With care for the last pair, you could also rotate the list:

```
   n ,: n
1 2 2 2 3 3 1
1 2 2 2 3 3 1
   (] ,: 1&|.) n
1 2 2 2 3 3 1
2 2 2 3 3 1 1
   =/(] ,: 1&|.) n
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

If you're particular about getting each item with its *previous* neighbor:

```
   2|.\1 2 3 4
2 1
3 2
4 3
```

There's also the 'subarrays' use of cut:

```
   2 <;.3 n
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬─┐
│1 2│2 2│2 2│2 3│3 3│3 1│1│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴─┘
   2 <;._3 n
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│1 2│2 2│2 2│2 3│3 3│3 1│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
   2 =/;._3 n
0 1 1 0 1 0
```

---

Belatedly, after learning a little bit of Q, this usage of each-prior:

```
q)deltas 10 15 20
10 5 5
q)\
  -':10 15 20
10 5 5
```

Is duplicated in J with a similar dyadic use of `\`:

```
   <\10 15 20
┌──┬─────┬────────┐
│10│10 15│10 15 20│
└──┴─────┴────────┘
   2 <\10 15 20
┌─────┬─────┐
│10 15│15 20│
└─────┴─────┘
   2 <\0 , 10 15 20
┌────┬─────┬─────┐
│0 10│10 15│15 20│
└────┴─────┴─────┘
   2 -~/\0 , 10 15 20
10 5 5
   deltas =: 2 -~/\ 0&,
   deltas 10 15 20
10 5 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is super thorough. Follow up question. Can you briefly help me understand the `"(1)` expression when comparing equality?

Comment: @andrewnc that's the [Rank conjunction](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/quote), I'm using it here on `/` to get row-wise instead of column-wise effect. The parens are just to keep it from looking like a part of the number after. `blah"1 ] 2` is another way to do that.